# Trouble using a React component from an older version of React in v16.x

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm relatively new to React but have found it productive in the past week. But I ran into sort of a conundrum.

I built a new project off of `create-react-app` CLI, which has the latest React v16.x and related packages included. However, the project I'm working on also requires an in-house package used by many other internal projects (hence I can't just go change things around). And it's built with React v15.x.

Here's the problem: When I `import` a component from that in-house package, I ran into the issue of React v16 having deprecated `React.PropTypes` syntax (which is still available in React v15.x).

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'oneOf' of undefined
```

The context of above `undefined` being `React.PropTypes.oneOf(...)` in the legacy v15 React module.

So how do I have the best of both worlds? Continue with v16.x on the project while being able to leverage components in packages from another era (v15.x)?

Thanks!

Comment: It's better if you stick with react `15.x` until your in-house project is also upgraded to 16 but you can change all the legacy code to use `prop-type` package which is separate from react now, and pave the way for them to easily upgrade to 16 at a later time.

Comment: I think you mentioned a couple of reasonable options. If you want to write it up as an answer, I'll mark it "answered" and call it a day. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here's the answer based on the comment I left:

For the most part it's a safer choice if you stick with react `15.x` until the code you depend on is updated to `16.x` as well. Just make sure you use `prop-types` package in your own code so you don't have to do the same migration again later.

For the legacy code you can start installing the `prop-types` package and change their schema to use that. Instead of:

```
import React from 'react';

Something.propTypes = {
  name: React.PropTypes.string
};
```

Use:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

Something.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string
};
```

This should be very easy with a simple `find/replace` and your team and the maintainers will thank you :)

Comment: I did end up downgrading my project to the latest v15 release of ReactJS. And just for the sake of experiment/completeness, I also updated the dependency project from React.PropTypes to `prop-types` as you mentioned, for future compatibility. Thanks again!